# The rigorous definition of continuity in a topological space

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $T_1 = \left({S_1, \tau_1}\right)$ and $T_2 = \left({S_2, \tau_2}\right)$ be topological spaces.

Let $f: S_1 \to S_2$ be a mapping from $S_1$ to $S_2$.

Let $x \in S_1$.

In this page [Proof Wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Continuous_Mapping_(Topology)/Point/Open_Sets), it is said that the mapping $f$ is continuous at (the point) $x$ (with respect to the topologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$) if and only if: For every neighborhood $N$ of $f(x)$ in $T_2$, there exists a neighborhood $M$ of $x$ in $T_1$ such that $f[M]\subseteq N$.

But in my knowledge, the condition should be $\forall y \in S_1 $, $y \in M \Rightarrow f(y) \in N$ instead of $f[M]\subseteq N$. The problem is that the two statements are not equivalent: the former statement is equivalent to $M \subseteq f^{-1}[N]$ because
$$
y\in M \iff \{y\} \subseteq M \implies f[y] \subseteq f[M] \iff f(y) \in f[M]
$$
As a result, we have a condition $f(y) \in f[M] \Rightarrow f(y) \in N$, which is equivalent to $M \subseteq f^{-1}[N]$.

Would you check this out?

Comment: $y \in M \implies f(y) \in N$ iff $f([M] \subseteq N$.

Comment: Is it the case that $ A\subseteq f^{-1}[B] \iff f[A] \subseteq B$?

Comment: I am not sure $\{y\} \subseteq M \iff f[y] \subseteq f[M]$ is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\forall y \in M: f(y) \in N$$ and $$f[M]\subseteq N$$

are exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that
$$f[M] \subseteq N\iff M \subseteq f^{-1}[N]$$.
I am sorry for the noise.